# Trigonometric values of complex Numbers

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, soft-question, recreational-mathematics

Is it sensible and mathematically correct to extend the definitions of the trigonometric ratios into the complex plane?  If yes, then how And why?

Also, does the following set of equations hold true?

$$e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$
If we let $x=i$, then we have
\begin{align}
e^{i^{2}} &= \cos(i) + i\sin(i)\\
e^{-1} &= \cos(i) + i\sin(i)\\
1&=e(\cos(i) + i\sin(i))
\end{align}

Also ,**what is the need to define trigonometric ratios in the complex plane??**
What are it's practical implementations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is all correct.

From the basic formulas $e^{\pm it}=\cos t \pm i\sin t$ one has
$$\cos t = \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}$$ $$\sin t = \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$$
It's also easy to show that
$$\cos it = \cosh t$$ $$\sin it = i\sinh t$$ which, with the usual addition formulas, gives
$$\cos (x+iy) = \cos x \cosh y - i\sin x\sinh y$$
$$\sin(x+iy) = \sin x \cosh y + i \cos x\sinh y$$
All of the other trig functions are defined in the obvious way using these.

Hyperbolic functions, and inverse trig/hyperbolic functions work the same way.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it sensible and mathematically correct to extend the definitions of trigonometric ratios in the complex plane?

Yes

> If yes, then how?

Starting from $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$, we can substitute $x := -x$ to get $e^{-ix} = \cos(-x) + i\sin(-x)$, and then by standard properties we get $e^{-ix} = \cos(x) - i\sin(x)$. Therefore $$\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}2 \\ \sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

> And why?

One option is to *define* the three functions by their Taylor expansions: $$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots \\
\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \cdots \\
\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \cdots$$

Comment: You left off $i$ in denominator of ratio for $\sin z$

Comment: @Peter Taylor  . So ,the value of cos(i) = $\frac{e^{2}+1}{2e}$ is a real number?

Comment: @MPW, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit, yes.

Comment: A very clear answer but IMHO part (3) didn't provide enough motivation for _why?_  The fact that the Taylor expansions work naturally for complex inputs does not justify why that would be useful.  Indeed, what are some applications where trig functions with complex domain are useful?

Comment: @antkam, the question wasn't why it's useful, but why it's mathematically correct.

Comment: haha, i see, then you certainly answered it.  i thought you were addressing the "what is the need..." part of the OP's questions.  anyway, can you shed some light, e.g. share some references / links, as to why it's useful?  complex analysis is very far from my usual areas but this thread made me curious...  (and of course, "it's worth studying for its own sake" is a fully acceptable answer too, if that is what it is.)

Comment: @antkam, I'm no analyst either. I suspect that the answer is that since the complex exponential is more fundamental, any applications would normally be phrased in terms of that rather than of sin and cos.